Monte Carlo simulations with extremely high volatility
I am using monte Carlo simulations to price a forex option. This is a standard model and works very well with less than 1 % error from black scholes price for 10000 simulations. But, as I increase volatility, this error increases . Also, at extremely high volatility, like 100 percent and more, the error terms increase exponentially. Why does this happen?

Do the results of your MC change materially if you re-run the MC with a different program seed? If so, try increasing the number of simulationa.

If you run $n$ simulations of your (suppose unbiased) estimator $X$ and take the average then the Monte-Carlo error is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}-\mathbb{E}(X)\xrightarrow{n\mapsto \infty}\mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{{\rm Var}(X)}{n}\right)
\end{equation}
distributed in the limit, due to the Central Limit Theorem. If you augment the volatility of the model, then the random variable $S_T$ has more variance, and $X=f(S_T)$ too, meaning your Monte-Carlo error increments in variance. The map
\begin{equation}
\sigma \mapsto {\rm Var}(S^\sigma_T)=C(e^{\sigma^2 T}-1)
\end{equation}
is of exponential growth just see this, and if $X=f(S_T)$ is piecewise linear, then you can expect an exponential blow-up in the variance and the confidence intervals of your Monte-Carlo solution.

It also depends how the radnom draws are simulated. If you use antithetics or Halton sequences, the error is considerably lower as the random numbers are negatively correlated. Consequently, your confidence level converges faster to the desired value.

I guess if you have correlation then you'd have a weaker version of the CLT. Does the variance still blow-up exponentially even with correlated adequately chosen $X_i$?

Thank you  everyone, it was really helpful

As the volatility increases, the spectrum of possible outcomes for $S_T$ increases (due to a more "choppy" evolution that fluctuates with a wider "up and down" range as well). As the output of the Monte Carlo simulation is an average of the intrinsic values at maturity discounted at the riskless rate to the current time, the same number of terminal intrinsic values (across a wider distribution) gives rise to a larger potential deviation from the true (Black-Scholes) price of an European option.

But even after 10000 simulations, the expected price of option is coming to be appro zero, which is very different from bsm, which Is nearly 82(strike price). I took Sigma to be 1000%. I know it is an absurd number but am trying to understand which underlying assumptions are creating a difference

I think 10k simulations might be way too little for 1000% sigma.

Understood , thank you.

If you found my comments to be helpful, I would appreciate an upvote on my solution (or acceptance as answer unless you already have accepted another as the answer), thanks!

When payoff is close [1,1.01,1.001,1.0001], you can actually use any probability distribution to find it's mean, the mean is going to be 1. Infact you don't even want to know the distribution of the underlying to evaluate this, it's going to be 1.
When payoff is apart [10,100,1000,10000],
you have to be very careful how much weight is put on each, as error will be quite large. You want to know the distribution exactly here.
Infact you will want to measure the mass at 10000 at 10 times more precision than mass of everything else.
